# Is a URL like example.com#utm_source=xxx recognized in Google analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I have a question about Google Analytics site speed. We have a lot of outside promotion links like

```
http://example.com?utm_source=xxx&utm_media=xxx
```

But this URL will load non-cached content because the URL is different each time. I tried changing `?utm_source` to `#utm_source`. How can I confirm that this will be recognized in Google Analytics?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use a hash in your links and replace the hash character in a virtual pageview:

```
if(document.location.hash.indexOf('utm' > -1) {   
 ga('send', 'pageview', document.location.pathname + document.location.search.replace('#','?'));
}
```

That way Google would "see" a normal query string when a utm parameter is present after the hash mark. Or you could replace the hash character with a replace filter inside the analytics interface.

Comment: I like to keep utm_xxx conent, to keep to analytic sources. but we have some static file create by normal path for website, i like to use these files to boost site performance, is there other way can do it?